# illegalStateException in android

Tags: android, illegalstateexception

I taken sound recording code from 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/index.html, after running it on my emulator it is throwing illegalStateException, I also tried in my device, but there also its same thing.

I am new to android, please help me

```
package com.android.audiorecordtest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;

import java.io.IOException;


public class AudioRecordTest extends Activity
{
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "AudioRecordTest";
    private static String mFileName = null;

    private RecordButton mRecordButton = null;
    private MediaRecorder mRecorder = null;

    private PlayButton   mPlayButton = null;
    private MediaPlayer   mPlayer = null;

    private void onRecord(boolean start) {
        if (start) {
            startRecording();
        } else {
            stopRecording();
        }
    }

    private void onPlay(boolean start) {
        if (start) {
            startPlaying();
        } else {
            stopPlaying();
        }
    }

    private void startPlaying() {
        mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        try {
            mPlayer.setDataSource(mFileName);
            mPlayer.prepare();
            mPlayer.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "prepare() failed");
        }
    }

    private void stopPlaying() {
        mPlayer.release();
        mPlayer = null;
    }

    private void startRecording() {
        mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        mRecorder.setOutputFile(mFileName);
        mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);

        try {
            mRecorder.prepare();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "prepare() failed");
        }

        mRecorder.start();
    }

    private void stopRecording() {
        mRecorder.stop();
        mRecorder.release();
        mRecorder = null;
    }

    class RecordButton extends Button {
        boolean mStartRecording = true;

        OnClickListener clicker = new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onRecord(mStartRecording);
                if (mStartRecording) {
                    setText("Stop recording");
                } else {
                    setText("Start recording");
                }
                mStartRecording = !mStartRecording;
            }
        };

        public RecordButton(Context ctx) {
            super(ctx);
            setText("Start recording");
            setOnClickListener(clicker);
        }
    }

    class PlayButton extends Button {
        boolean mStartPlaying = true;

        OnClickListener clicker = new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onPlay(mStartPlaying);
                if (mStartPlaying) {
                    setText("Stop playing");
                } else {
                    setText("Start playing");
                }
                mStartPlaying = !mStartPlaying;
            }
        };

        public PlayButton(Context ctx) {
            super(ctx);
            setText("Start playing");
            setOnClickListener(clicker);
        }
    }

    public AudioRecordTest() {
        mFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
        mFileName += "/audiorecordtest.3gp";
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);

        LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        mRecordButton = new RecordButton(this);
        ll.addView(mRecordButton,
            new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                0));
        mPlayButton = new PlayButton(this);
        ll.addView(mPlayButton,
            new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                0));
        setContentView(ll);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (mRecorder != null) {
            mRecorder.release();
            mRecorder = null;
        }

        if (mPlayer != null) {
            mPlayer.release();
            mPlayer = null;
        }
    }
}
```

**Stack Trace:**

```
> 06-01 11:06:18.440:
> ERROR/AndroidRuntime(724): Uncaught
> handler: thread main exiting due to
> uncaught exception 06-01 11:06:18.449:
> ERROR/AndroidRuntime(724):
> java.lang.IllegalStateException 06-01
> 11:06:18.449:
> ERROR/AndroidRuntime(724):     at
> android.media.MediaRecorder.start(Native
> Method) 06-01 11:06:18.449:
> ERROR/AndroidRuntime(724):     at
> com.example.android.whereareyou.Main.startRecording(Main.java:75)
> 06-01 11:06:18.449:
> ERROR/AndroidRuntime(724):     at
> com.example.android.whereareyou.Main.onRecord(Main.java:32)
> 06-01 11:06:18.449:
> ERROR/AndroidRuntime(724):     at
> com.example.android.whereareyou.Main.access$0(Main.java:30)
> 06-01 11:06:18.449:
> ERROR/AndroidRuntime(724):     at
> com.example.android.whereareyou.Main$RecordButton$1.onClick(Main.java:89)
> 06-01 11:06:18.449:
> ERROR/AndroidRuntime(724):     at
> android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2179)
> 06-01 11:06:18.449:
> ERROR/AndroidRuntime(724):     at
> android.view.View.onTouchEvent(View.java:3828)
> 06-01 11:06:18.449:
> ERROR/AndroidRuntime(724):     at
> android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:6291)
> 06-01 11:06:18.449:
> ERROR/AndroidRuntime(724):     at
> android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3368)
> 06-01 11:06:18.449:
> ERROR/AndroidRuntime(724):     at
> android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:863)
> 06-01 11:06:18.449:
> ERROR/AndroidRuntime(724):     at
> android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:863)
> 06-01 11:06:18.449:
> ERROR/AndroidRuntime(724):     at
> android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:863)
> 06-01 11:06:18.449:
> ERROR/AndroidRuntime(724):     at
> android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:863)
> 06-01 11:06:18.449:
> ERROR/AndroidRuntime(724):     at
> com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1707)
> 06-01 11:06:18.449:
> ERROR/AndroidRuntime(724):     at
> com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1197)
> 06-01 11:06:18.449:
> ERROR/AndroidRuntime(724):     at
> android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:1993)
> 06-01 11:06:18.449:
> ERROR/AndroidRuntime(724):     at
> com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1691)
> 06-01 11:06:18.449:
> ERROR/AndroidRuntime(724):     at
> android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1525)
> 06-01 11:06:18.449:
> ERROR/AndroidRuntime(724):     at
> android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
> 06-01 11:06:18.449:
> ERROR/AndroidRuntime(724):     at
> android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
> 06-01 11:06:18.449:
> ERROR/AndroidRuntime(724):     at
> android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3948)
> 06-01 11:06:18.449:
> ERROR/AndroidRuntime(724):     at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native
> Method) 06-01 11:06:18.449:
> ERROR/AndroidRuntime(724):     at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
> 06-01 11:06:18.449:
> ERROR/AndroidRuntime(724):     at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:782)
> 06-01 11:06:18.449:
> ERROR/AndroidRuntime(724):     at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:540)
> 06-01 11:06:18.449:
> ERROR/AndroidRuntime(724):     at
> dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native
> Method)
```

Comment: please post the stacktrace of your exception from logcat

Comment: whether the recording happens or not... Are you getting any ANR Dialog...

Comment: Could you please post your Manifest file, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use that:-

```
public class VoiceRecorder extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
private MediaRecorder mediaRecorder;
boolean recording= false;
private Button start; //Start Button to start the recordings
private Button stop; // Stop button to stop the recordings
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.voice_recorder);
    mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    start = (Button)findViewById(R.id.start);

    //Activity when user click the start Button
    start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            settings();
            recordPrepare();
            mediaRecorder.start();
            recording = true;

        }

    });

    //Activity when user click the stop Button
    stop = (Button)findViewById(R.id.stop);
    stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if(recording)
            {
                mediaRecorder.stop();
                mediaRecorder.release();
                recording = false;
                settings();
                recordPrepare();
            }

        }
    });
}
//Settings for Audio Recorder
private void settings()
{
    long name = new Date().getTime();
    mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.DEFAULT);
    mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.DEFAULT);
    mediaRecorder.setOutputFile("/sdcard/"+Long.toString(name)+".3gp");
    DataModel dbModel = new DataModel(this);
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    dbModel.insertMultimedia("/sdcard/"+Long.toString(name)+".3gp", Long.toString(name), cal);
}
//prepare the Environment for Recording
private void recordPrepare()
{
    try
    {
        mediaRecorder.prepare();
    }
    catch(IllegalStateException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();

    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

This will work fine. and file will be stored into SD card. you can also play by using play method as you have used in your code.

Answer (score 3):

The problem in the code provided there is that the name of the filename where you record (mFileName) is null.

You can just call `AudioRecordTest()` before calling `mRecorder.setOutputFile(mFileName)` on `startRecording()` method. That should work. At least it did for me.